# How to split columns into two in oracle sql based in character?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set as below

Table name :  Customer_tbl

| Customer_ID | Customer_post |
| --- | --- |
| 12985 | 201 |
| 20917$@98821$@749021$@357831 | 201$@29$@29$@29 |
| 548357$@276031 | 201$@34 |
| 80315$@75344$@345621 | 201$@29$@14 |

Output I need is as below

| Customer_ID_1 | Customer_ID_2 | Customer_post_1 | Customer_post_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12985 |  | 201 |  |
| 20917 | 98821$@749021$@357831 | 201 | 29$@29$@29 |
| 548357 | 276031 | 201$@34 | 34 |
| 80315 | 75344$@345621 | 201$@29$@14 | 29$@14 |

I got the Customer_ID_1  & Customer_post_1   as below

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(Customer_ID,'[^|@]+',1,1)  as Customer_ID_1 ,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(Customer_post,'[^|@]+',1,1)  as  Customer_post_1
FROM Customer_tbl
```

How to get the  Customer_ID_2  and Customer_post_2 columns in the same select statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already get with your Query everything before '@'.
→ You just need everything after '@'.

This query provides exactly the desired output for the sample data provided:

```
SELECT 
  replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Customer_ID,'[^|@]+',1,1),'$','')  as Customer_ID_1 , -- everything before '@' and remove '$'
  regexp_replace(Customer_ID,'^([0-9]+[$@]*)','')  as Customer_ID_2 , -- everything after '$@' or '@$' and remove this match
  replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Customer_post,'[^|@]+',1,1),'$','')  as  Customer_post_1, -- everything after '$@' or '@$' and remove this match
  regexp_replace(Customer_post,'^([0-9]+[$@]*)','')  as  Customer_post_2, -- everything after '@'
FROM Customer_tbl
;
```

How it works :

- ^([0-9]+[$@]*) → matches a string that begins like "12985", "548357$@" or "1@$"
- At least one number must be followed by "$@" or "@$"
- The "regexp_replace" can replace this match with something. In this case I replaced the match with an empty string ''.  So that you get only the last part.
- When "regexp_replace" does not find a match for the regular expression, NULL will return.

If you want to test such queries yourself (e.g if you have problems with a special string), you can do it as follows:

```
select regexp_replace('201$@29$@29$@29','^([0-9]+[$@]*)','') from dual;
```

Just put the problematic string in

```
select regexp_replace('Put_your_String_here' ....
```

Here can you find some useful references for oracle regexp-functions:

- regexp_substr https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php
- regexp_replace https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php
- regexp_instr https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_instr.php

... and of course the official oracle reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490

Comment: Links to the official documentation would be better as they describe all the functionality and restrictions: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490